# java Spring-MVC 4+HTML+CSS+Javascript

Tags: javascript, java, html, jsp, spring-mvc

При работе с html(точнее JSP) страницей при подключении js файлов полностью слетают стили. Подключаю так:

```
<head>
    <link href="/static/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
    <script src="/static/js/scripts.js" rel="script" type="text/javascript"/>
</head>
```

Что я неправильно делаю?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещен в чат](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/42001/discussion-on-question-by---java-spring-mvc-4htmlcssjavascript).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Тег script самозакрывающимся не бывает, и это главная проблема которая мешала жить. 
Атрибута rel у тега script нет. Надо так:

```
<script src="/static/js/scripts.js" type="text/javascript"> </script>
```